# List fonts from another directory

Tags: vb.net

I have a list box that I am trying to populate, showing font names.  The source is a folder that contains 1,000+ font files (.ttf's, .fon's)  I am able to populate the list box with the file names of what is in the folder, but I need to list the font names (Calibri, Arial, etc)

The folder with the font files is not the fonts installed on the client, it is a separate folder under the root o C:\

Can anyone please assist, I just can not figure this one out?

Comment: Private Sub LoadList1()
        Dim directory = "c:\Odds & Ends\FontSync\MasterFontList"
        Dim files() As System.IO.FileInfo
        Dim dirinfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directory)
        'files = dirinfo.GetFiles("*.ttf")
        files = dirinfo.GetFiles("*.ttf").Union(dirinfo.GetFiles("*.fon")).ToArray()
        For Each file In files
            ListBox1.Items.Add(file.Name)
        Next

    End Sub

Comment: The above is the code where I can successfully populate the list box with the file names

Comment: Please read [Ask] and take the [tour],  Code you need help with needs to be in the post where it formats properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited answer to get all the font families of all the ttf,fon and otf files in a directory and add them to a listbox

Add this line to the top of your code..

```
Imports System.Drawing.Text
```

declare the following in your form class - you can use these later on to refer back to the actual font objects of you're going to use the fonts

The following code takes these parameters:-

lstbox is the listbox that you want to add the family names to.
directoryPath is the directory you want to search
srcOption is one of two options -

Searchoption.TopDirectoryOnly - to search only the specified directory

SearchOption.AllDirectories - to seach the specified directory and all sub-directories.

```
Private Sub PopulateListboxWithFontFamilies(lstbox As ListBox, directoryPath As String, srchoption As SearchOption)

    Dim ListOfFontFamilyNames As New ListBox.ObjectCollection(lstbox)
    Dim privateFonts As New System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection()
    Dim directory As New DirectoryInfo(directoryPath)
    For Each file As FileInfo In directory.GetFileSystemInfos("*.ttf", srchoption)
        privateFonts.AddFontFile(file.FullName)
    Next
    For Each file As FileInfo In directory.GetFileSystemInfos("*.fon", srchoption)
        privateFonts.AddFontFile(file.FullName)
    Next
    For Each file As FileInfo In directory.GetFileSystemInfos("*.otf", srchoption)
        privateFonts.AddFontFile(file.FullName)
    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To privateFonts.Families.Count - 1
        ListOfFontFamilyNames.Add(privateFonts.Families(i).Name)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU for your quick response........The above will give the fonts that are installed on the client.  I need the above, but for font files not installed, residing in a folder on the hard drive.

Comment: Ok I am almost there................ how do I make the below .getFiles statement get files with a .otf extension as well?

Comment: Dim files As String() = Directory.GetFiles("c:\Odds & Ends\FontSync\MasterFontList", "*.ttf")

Comment: @JeffreyRoccaforte Edited answer. I think it should work now